# How do I stop setInterval after a specific second count? - clearInterval not activating in a conditional, ex: if (count > 3)

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I realize this question has been asked quite a bit, but still I cannot get clearInterval to kick in. Surely something simple I'm missing:

```
...

let count = 0;

var intCount = null;
var intPic = null;
 
function Shuffle () {
  intCount = setInterval(Count, 1000);
  intPic = setInterval(ChangePic, 200);

  if (count > 3) {
    clearInterval(intCount);
    clearInterval(intPic);
  }
}

function Count () {
  count++;
}

...
```

Shuffle() comes from a click and triggers the setIntervals and the count does increase (well beyond 4) and never stops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setInterval is an async task. Event loop comes into picture for this.When shuffle is clicked, it creates two setIntervals and shuffle function finishes execution. so for each interval iteration, js engine has access to count and changPic function. you can write your conditional there.
Put your count check in Count function.

```
let count = 0;

var intCount = null;
var intPic = null;

function Shuffle () {
  intCount = setInterval(Count, 1000);
  intPic = setInterval(ChangePic, 200);
}

function Count () {
   if (count > 3) {
      clearInterval(intCount);
      clearInterval(intPic);
   } else {
      count++;
   }
}
```